# I cannot get Postman to DELETE an entry even though it will GET it for me. This is in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I am working on a React/Express app. There is a delete button, but it is only returning errors:

xhr.js:251     DELETE http://localhost:3333/entries/2 404 (Not Found)

AND

EntryDetails.js:39 Error Deleting entry: AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

I went to Postman and tried to delete and it also wouldn't work. I got :

```
Cannot DELETE /entries/2
```

This is true for several different entry numbers that I tried. Oddly, I can send a GET request just fine.

I have checked the route configuration and spelling and put in console.logs. The database is configured and accessible. I have checked that a table named entries exists. (I am using postgres.) It is a simple table and doesn't connect to any other table, so there shouldn't be any relevant constraints.

I originally had an error in the delete route that had entry instead of entries, but I changed that and restarted both the frontend and the backend several times since then.

I thought maybe it had to do with the order of code, so I moved entries.delete after entries.get, entries.post, and entries.put.

I put some code below.

```
entryController.js

const express = require("express");
const entries = express.Router();
const {
    getAllEntries,
    getEntry,
    createEntry,
    updateEntry,
    deleteEntry,
} = require("../queries/entries")

[snip]

// =====  DELETE  =====
entries.delete('/entries/:id', async(req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const deletedEntry = await deleteEntry(id);
    if (deletedEntry.id) {
        res.status(200).json(deletedEntry);
    } else {
        res.status(404).json( {error: "Entry not found."} );
    }
});


module.exports = entries;
```

```
entries.js

const db = require("../db/dbconfig");

[SNIP]

// === DELETE AN ENTRY (DESTROY) ===
const deleteEntry = async(id) => {
    try {const deletedEntry = await db.one(
        "DELETE FROM entries WHERE id = $1 RETURNING *", id
    );
    return deletedEntry;
    } catch(error){
        return error;
        }
};

[SNIP]


module.exports = { 
    getAllEntries,
    getEntry,
    createEntry,
    updateEntry,
    deleteEntry,
    billsToSendToInsurance,
}
```

I think the route handling is okay, if that is even relevant.

```
  const deleteEntry = () => {
    console.log("deleteEntry");
    const deleteURL = `${API}/entries/${id}`;
    console.log(deleteURL);
    axios.delete(deleteURL, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
      .then((response) => {
        navigate(`/entries`);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error("Error Deleting entry:", error));
  };
```

I do not know if it is related, but I also cannot update an entry without updating ALL the entries.

Any suggestions?

---

Editing to add in response to comments:
In app.js, I have

```
const entryController = require("./controllers/entryController.js");
    app.use("/entries", entryController);
```

The API in deleteURL is

```
 const API = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
```

Comment: Please share the code where you are redirecting the calls to `entryController.js` and what is your API variable in `const deleteURL = ${API}/entries/${id};`

Comment: Thanks @ravi. I have changed the question to include the following. The API in deleteURL is `const API = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;` and the controller info is `const entryController = require("./controllers/entryController.js");
    app.use("/entries", entryController);`

Comment: @JenniferE. I think I found the issue, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, you are redirecting all `/entries` calls to the entryController

```
app.use("/entries", entryController);
```

and then inside the controller while calling delete, again using `/entries` in the path

```
entries.delete('/entries/:id', async(req, res) => {
    // your code...
});
```

So this effectively makes the route as `${API}/entries/entries/:id`
which obviously does not exist.

To fix this, just remove `/entries` on delete call

```
entries.delete('/:id', async(req, res) => {
    // your code...
});
```

And then it should work.

Comment: It worked! It worked!  Thank you so much! I don't have enough reputation to cast a vote for your very correct answer, but it has recorded my feedback for when I do. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it helped! You can still accept this answer, accepting does not require any minimum reputation.

Comment: I finally just looked up HOW to accept an answer. And...done! Thanks again.